# Connecting to MySQL database running on Raspberry Pi using Windows Laptop/PI (LAN cable)

Tags: pi-3, database

I am sorry if this sounds funny as I am a complete noob when it comes to database configuration. I have been trying to access my Pi's MySQL database from my laptop/or another PI. I have successfully linked PHP and Libreoffice Base (via ODBC) to the database using localhost. By using my mySQL Pi, tables can be created and by typing 127.0.1.1/phpmyadmin, I can access my tables using a web browser with ease. Right now, I connected a LAN cable to my laptop/my 2nd pi and my mySQL pi and I am wondering if I can access it locally this way?(Using microsoft access/web browser) but when I entered 127.0.1.1/phpmyadmin on my laptop/ other pi's browser it doesn't load.

Is it because my laptop or pi's Lan ip is not approved on my main mySQL pi? I have also tried to edit /etc/mysql/my.cnf and commented out #bind-address on my pi. Thank you so much for reading this long query. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is a local address (local to the machine) so if you are using this on your laptop it will look for the DB on your laptop not the Pi. You will need to use the IP of the Pi hosting the DB.

Comment: @SteveRobillard Thank you for the reply. Which IP should I use? the local eth0 gateway by using ifconfig?

Comment: You need the IP of the PI.

Answer (score 1):

Find the ip address of your mysql pi by entering ifconfig at the command line on the pi console. Then use that address from your laptop/browser.
As the other responder mentioned the 127.0.0.1 address is the local address of the computer you are working on.